# How to Continuously Loop Through a Column of Zip Codes (~10000) using VBA to Process them through the Excel "Geography" Link Data?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, zipcode

I am attempting to use VBA to loop through about 10000 rows of zip codes using the
[Geography Linked Data Tab](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiI_tve6NPiAhVXuZ4KHWJ3CEMQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechcommunity.microsoft.com%2Ft5%2FExcel-Blog%2FPreview-of-Stocks-and-Geography-New-Data-Types-in-Excel%2Fba-p%2F176185&psig=AOvVaw22Ld-CnfPS_Riro4iJHDpr&ust=1559874662991121) (pictured here).  Since I am unable to select all of them and just press the button, I have to loop in a selected range of about 400 rows or less.

I will update this tomorrow with the actual code since I am unable to reproduce it on my phone, but hopefully this will give a general idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
For Row 2 to 10540

 range("D" & Row, "D" & Row + 300).select

  [Action that is applied to data goes here]

Next
```

Comment: The [`Range.ConvertToLinkedDataType` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.converttolinkeddatatype) should be helpful as far as the conversion goes. Is the loop required because the rows are not continuous?

Comment: @BigBen That looks like it should help, i'll take a closer look at the documentation.  The rows are continuous, however it gives me an error saying something like I have exceeded the amount of external queries for the day...or something along those lines when I try to do any selection above 400 or so.  But it still lets me do more even though it says I have exceeded the limit for the day.

Comment: Please read [How to Avoid Using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)